# Include proprocessor directives in the application

Tags: blackberry

Hi all I am starting an application where I have to specify some xml files in the application for some button fields.  When I click on one button it should parse the specified xml file.  How can I make call them call before compile time, mean how to mention in preprocessor directives.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use the preprocessor directives in Java source files - so if the XML you are referencing is defined in Java code (or the URLs pointing to them is in Java code), then you could use the preprocessor this case.  The important thing to remember is to add `//#preprocess` as the very first line in your .java file, otherwise it will not be pre-processed.

More information can be found at http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/12002/Specifying_preprocessor_directives_657636_11.js